# SQL query for parent child with no relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, parent-child

I need help regarding a query that I want to create. For instance, let's say I have this table:

```
Description                     Level     Is_Active
----------------------------------------------------
 (1)Metallic industry products        1          1
 (2)+ Various metal products          2          1
 (3)++  Other metal products          3          1
 (1)Rubber and plastic products       1          1
 (2)+ Rubber products                 2          1
 (2)+ Other rubber products           2          1
 (3)++  Other product types           3          1
```

where level specifies the relationship. The records in the table are set to reproduce a tree structure. What I'm trying to do is a query which selects all the parents with children from this table that are active. If, for instance, the Is_Active column for Metallic industry products is set to 0, I don't want to display it and it's children (arious metal products and other metal products).

The same for Various metal products, if it's not active, don't display it and it's children. I tried joining with the same table or using the WITH function but sadly I can't find a solution.

A more concrete example is this. Metallic industry products becomes inactive. Then the select result should be:

```
Description                     Level     Is_Active
----------------------------------------------------
 (1)Rubber and plastic products       1          1
 (2)+ Rubber products                 2          1
 (2)+ Other rubber products           2          1
 (3)++  Other product types           3          1
```

Or let's say the child of Metallic industry products becomes inactive. The result set should be like this:

```
Description                     Level     Is_Active
----------------------------------------------------
 (1)Metallic industry products        1          1
 (1)Rubber and plastic products       1          1
 (2)+ Rubber products                 2          1
 (2)+ Other rubber products           2          1
 (3)++  Other product types           3          1
```

Comment: What does your desired resultset look like?

Comment: The result set should be something like this: if Metallic industry products has Is_Active set to 0, select all the records from Rubber and plastic products and so on. The first three should not appear in the selection because Various metal products and Other metal products are children of Metallic industry products and this one is inactive.

Comment: It is doable, but the basic problem is that the data hasn't been normalised. There should be a key and parent_key columns. You would then simply be able to do a self-join.

Comment: I know. Without key and parent key column I don't think it will be easy. The data was stored in the table using a hard coded algorhytm. And I don't know if my boss will be pleased if I add another parent_key column

Comment: OK, so does the data come out of the table in the correct order with a basic select?

Comment: Yes. Doing a simple select brings the data like i mentioned above.

Comment: OK, I'll see what I can come up with...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've had a go and it isn't pretty, but see what you think. I've used WHILE loops rather than cursors to minimise the code:

```
  create table #ordered_products
(id int identity(1,1),
 grouping int default 0,
 Description varchar(128),
 level int,
 is_active bit);

 insert into #ordered_products (Description, level, is_active)
 select description, level, is_active from products;

-- All rows now have an order

declare @grouping int = 0;
declare @currentid int;
declare @found bit = 1;
declare @level int;
declare @base int;

set @currentid = (select min(id) from #ordered_products);

-- Go through all the rows setting a new group each time we hit level 1

while (@found = 1)
begin
  set @level = (select level from #ordered_products where id = @currentid);

  if (@level = 1)
  begin
    set @grouping = @grouping + 1
  end

  update #ordered_products set grouping = @grouping where id = @currentid

  set @currentid = @currentid + 1;
  set @found = (select 1 from #ordered_products where id = @currentid);

end

-- For each group, set the children to be inactive if the parent is

declare @maxgroup int = (select MAX(GROUPING) from #ordered_products);

declare @currentgroup int = 1;

while (@currentgroup <= @maxgroup)
begin

    begin
        set @base = (select MIN(id) from #ordered_products where is_active = 0 and grouping = @currentgroup);

        if (@base > 0)
        begin
            update #ordered_products set is_active = 0 where grouping = @currentgroup and id > @base;
        end
    end 

    set @currentgroup = @currentgroup + 1;  
end 

-- Output

select * from #ordered_products where is_active = 1;

drop table #ordered_products;
```